# Differential equation $y'=\frac{1-xy}{y-x^2}$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I tried many thing but I could not find a method to solve the  differential equation $$y'=\frac{1-xy}{y-x^2}$$

$$y'=-x+\frac{1-x^3}{y-x^2}$$

$Z=y-x^2$

$$Z'+2x=-x+\frac{1-x^3}{Z}$$

$$Z(Z'+3x)=1-x^3$$

Could you please give me hint which method can be used for such first order differential equations?
Thanks a lot for advice and answers

Comment: Your equation is equivalent with $$(1-xy)dx+(x^2-y)dy=0,$$ but $(1-xy)'_{y}=-x \neq 2x = (x^2-y)'_y$ Maybe we could find integration factor

Comment: Why do you think there is an explicit solution in known functions?

Comment: Maybe .I tried the method too but I could not find integration factor. Thanks for advice

Comment: Check this [solution](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=y%27%3D%281-xy%29%2F%28y-x%5E2%29).

Comment: @MhenniBeghorbal I would like to learn methods to get that result

Comment: If you interested in learning general techniques for solving differential equations, then you may need to learn [symmetry groups method](http://euler.nmt.edu/~jstarret/05-649LieGroupODEFinalVersion.pdf).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$y'=\dfrac{1-xy}{y-x^2}$

$(y-x^2)y'=1-xy$

Let $u=y-x^2$ ,

Then $y=u+x^2$

$y'=u'+2x$

$\therefore u(u'+2x)=1-x(u+x^2)$

$uu'+2xu=1-xu-x^3$

$uu'=-3xu-x^3+1$

Try to solve this ODE by [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=u%2au%27%3D-3xu-x%5E3%2B1), you will discover that the general solution is implicitly expressed by $x$ and $x+\dfrac{x^3-1}{u}$ .

Since Wolfram Alpha discover that the substitution $v=x+\dfrac{x^3-1}{u}$ leads the ODE becomes a separable ODE:

Let $v=x+\dfrac{x^3-1}{u}$ ,

Then $u=\dfrac{x^3-1}{v-x}$

$u'=\dfrac{3x^2(v-x)-(x^3-1)(v'-1)}{(v-x)^2}$

$\therefore\dfrac{x^3-1}{v-x}\dfrac{3x^2(v-x)-(x^3-1)(v'-1)}{(v-x)^2}=-3x\dfrac{x^3-1}{v-x}-x^3+1$

$\dfrac{3x^2(v-x)-(x^3-1)(v'-1)}{(v-x)^2}=-3x-(v-x)$

$3x^2(v-x)-(x^3-1)(v'-1)=-3x(v-x)^2-(v-x)^3$

$(x^3-1)(v'-1)=3x^2(v-x)+3x(v-x)^2+(v-x)^3$

$(x^3-1)v'-x^3+1=3x^2(v-x)+3x(v-x)^2+(v-x)^3$

$(x^3-1)v'=x^3+3x^2(v-x)+3x(v-x)^2+(v-x)^3-1$

$(x^3-1)v'=(x+v-x)^3-1$

$(x^3-1)v'=v^3-1$

Comment: Thanks a lot for wonderful answer. I wonder if we did not get help of wolframalpha how we could find the transform.

Answer (score 1):

Equation $$zz'=-3xz-x^3+1$$ is [Abel equation of the second kind](http://eqworld.ipmnet.ru/en/solutions/ode/ode0126.pdf). You can find [here](http://science.fire.ustc.edu.cn/download/download1/book/mathematics/Handbook%20of%20Exact%20Solutions%20for%20Ordinary%20Differential%20EquationsSecond%20Edition/c2972_fm.pdf)
some solvable Abel equation.

Good luck with finding your equation!